# domain name legal takeover

Tags: domains, legal

I was wondering; if I buy a domain name, say www.bananapeel.com. Then after a couple of years my site becomes big with plenty of revenue. Because of this someone decides to trademark the name "bananpeel". Does that then give them the right to legally take over my domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. [Source](http://www.intelproplaw.com/ip_forum/index.php?topic=11975.0)

> ..if you received your trademark
>   registration after the domain name was
>   registered, you will not have a solid
>   case for a domain name dispute unless
>   your mark was famous or well-known
>   prior to the date the domain name was
>   registered

However, if you attempt to capitalize on their trademark with that domain then they have recourse to recover that domain name from you.